# Firebase Functions + monorepo - Deploying doesn't work + deps not installed locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Looks like someone has the same problem here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1050

### Problem

I have moved my project structure to a monorepo with the following structure:

```
/
|
| - node_modules/
|
| - packages/
| - - app/
| - - - - index.js
| - - - - package.json
| - - functions/
| - - - - src/
| - - - - - - helloWorld.function.js
| - - - - - - index.js
| - - - - package.json
|
| - .firebaserc
| - firebase.json
| - firestore.indexes.json
| - firestore.rules
| - package.json
| - yarn.lock
| - LICENSE.md
```

As far as I know, all code our functions depends on must be inside the `functions` directory. But... when I run `yarn install`, the `node_modules` of my `functions` are saved in the `root node_modules folder`.

Then, if I run `firebase deploy` from the root of my project, I get the error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

*Note: I haven't made any **code** change... before configuring the project to the monorepo structure, everything worked fine.*

### My attempt to solve this problem

I have tried to use [nohoist](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/) when defining my workspaces inside my root package.json:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "@company/project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project monorepo",
  "repository": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "Raul",
    "email": "...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "app": "yarn workspace @company/app start",
    "documentation": "yarn workspace @company/documentation start",
    "server": "yarn workspace @company/server start"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "nohoist": ["**/@company/server"] <---- HERE
  }
}
```

-*Note: when I run `yarn server` the functions shell is started correctly.*

But... for some reason, after reinstalling everything:

```
rm -rf node_modules (everywhere)
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

**The dependencies of the functions packages are installed in the root `node_modules`!**

Any ideas?

---

This is how my functions node_modules looks like after installing the deps:

```
node_modules/ 
  .bin/ 
     eslint
     eslint-config-prettier
     firebase-functions
     functions-framework
     functions-framework-nodejs
     image_size
     uuid
  qs/
  uuid/
```

And these are the dependencies required (which are installed in the root package.json, which is not the behavior I expect):

```
 "name": "@company/server",
 ...
 "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.1.1",
    "@google-cloud/translate": "^6.3.1",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.4.2",
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "camelcase": "^6.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.21.2",
    "glob": "^7.2.0",
    "image-size": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "sharp": "^0.30.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  }
```

---

## UPDATE

Instead of nohoisting in the root, I have placed this segment in the `packages/functions/package.json`:

```
workspaces: { nohoist: ["**"] }
```

and all the deps are installed locally!

But... when I do `firebase deploy`, same error. If instead of running the command from the root folder I do it from `packages/functions/package.json` the deployment is successful.

Why? What is happening?

This is my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["yarn --cwd \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" lint"],
    "source": "packages/functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a solution and wrote an article about this. Below is an
excerpt, but here is the [full
article](https://thijs-koerselman.medium.com/deploy-to-firebase-without-the-hacks-e685de39025e)

> ### The problem with Firebase
>
> When deploying to Firebase it wants to upload a folder just like a
> traditional single package repository, containing the source files
> together with a manifest file declaring its external dependencies.
> After receiving the files in its cloud deployment pipeline, it then
> detects the package manager and runs an install and build.
>
> In a monorepo, and especially a private one, your Firebase code
> typically depend on one or more shared packages from the same
> repository, for which you have no desire to publish them anywhere.
>
> Once Firebase tries to look up those dependencies in the cloud they
> can not be found and deployment fails.
>
> ### Hacking your way out
>
> #### Using a bundler
>
> In order to solve this you could try to use a bundler like Webpack to
> combine your Firebase code with the shared packages code and then
> remove those packages from the package.json manifest that is being
> sent to Firebase, so it doesn’t know these packages even existed.
>
> Unfortunately, this strategy quickly becomes problematic…
>
> If the shared packages themselves do not bundle all of their
> dependencies in their output, Firebase doesn’t know what the shared
> code depends on, because you are not including or installing those
> manifests.
>
> You could try to bundle everything then, but if your shared package
> depends on things your Firebase package also depends on, you now have
> one part of your code running an internally bundled copy of a
> dependency and the other part using that same dependency from a
> different location installed by the package manager.
>
> Also, some libraries really don’t like to be bundled, and in my
> experience that includes the Firebase and Google client libraries. You
> will quickly find yourself trying to externalize things via the
> bundler settings in order get thing to work.
>
> And even if you managed to make all this work, you are probably
> creating large bundles which could then lead to problems with the
> cold-start times of your cloud functions.
>
> Not exactly a reliable or scalable solution.
>
> #### Packing and linking local dependencies
>
> An arguably more elegant approach involves packing the local
> dependencies into a tarball (similar to how a package would be
> published to NPM), and copying the results to the build output before
> linking them in an altered manifest file.
>
> This could work quite nicely, as it basically resembles how your
> Firebase code would have worked if these packages were installed from
> an external domain.
>
> Whether you’re doing this manually, or write a shell script to handle
> things, it still feels very cumbersome and fragile to me, but I think
> it is a viable workaround if your local dependencies are simple.
>
> However, this approach quickly becomes hairy once you have shared
> packages depending on other shared packages, because then you’ll have
> have multiple levels of things to pack and adapt.
>
> ### My solution
>
> I have created
> [isolate-package](https://github.com/0x80/isolate-package). The name
> is generic because it doesn’t contain anything specific to Firebase,
> although I currently don’t know of any other use-cases for isolated
> output.
>
> It takes a similar approach to what is described earlier in packing
> and linking dependencies, but does so in a more sophisticated way. It
> is designed to handle different setups and package managers and it
> completely hides the complexity from the user.
>
> The isolate binary it exposes can simply be added to the Firebase
> predeploy hook, and that’s pretty much it!
>
> This also allows you to deploy to Firebase from multiple different
> packages and keep the configuration co-located instead of littering
> the monorepo root directory.
>
> It should be zero-config for the vast majority of use-cases, and is
> designed to be compatible with all package managers.

Answer (score -1):

## Workaround (Not the correct solution, just a trick):

Instead of using `nohoist` to installing all the deps locally inside the `packages/functions` directory, what about excluding it from the `yarn workspaces`?

For this, update your root's `package.json` to:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/app",
    "packages/documentation"
  ]
```

(`packages/functions` is not included as a workspace.)

## Test it:

Now, if you run (wherever you want in your project) `firebase deploy`, everything works fine... the deployment is successful and all our backend deps are installed locally (it is required, since all the cloud functions code must be inside the functions folder).

Also, this [error](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1050) is solved too!

### Pros:

You can maintain the monorepository structure and deploy your cloud functions without problems.

### Cons:

This is a tricky solution... when you run `yarn install` from the root of your project, `packages/functions/package.json` dependencies are not installed (as we have remove it from the workspace in order to install them locally.)

In order to solve this little issue, in your root `package.json`, write the following:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "postinstall": "cd path/to/your/functions && yarn install", // automatically executed after running `yarn install`
  }
}
```

in my case:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "postinstall": "cd packages/functions && yarn install", // automatically executed after running `yarn install`
  }
}
```